# "Add To Wish List" in the Mac App Store?

Tags: mac, mac-appstore

Does anybody know if there is a way to "add to wish list" some apps at the Mac App Store and get noticed when their price drops just as in the iTunes Store?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think Apple has ever explained why such a feature is missing from the Mac App Store, so we don't know. You can create a wish list on AppShopper instead: http://appshopper.com/blog/2012/03/27/how-to-use-the-wish-list-feature-on-appshopper-com/

Comment: yeah, I use appshopper. The App store has a wishlist, but doesn't (or I haven't noticed) inform you of price drops.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no default mac app store wish list, all though, there are some 3 party applications and websites that allow you do track apps prices and add them to a wishlist. One of them is: http://www.appshopper.com/.